# React-native Single select card list / Radio button

Tags: react-native

I'm pretty new to react-native so any help would be really appreciated!

I am trying to create a list of cards that behave like radio buttons:

- The Items/Cards of the list are custom react-native components
- Only a single card can be selected at a time
- The style applied to a card depends on whether it is selected or not
- It should be possible to check which card is currently selected

Note that because of company restrictions, I have to do that with custom components, and can't use already made UI Kits like Native Base or React Native Elements.

Here is a screenshot of a quick visual example I did.

[image: Single Select Card List example]

Note that in the screenshot above, there are only two cards, however, there can be more cards in the list.

Here is what I have coded until now for the custom Card component:

```
// Card.js
export default class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={cardStyles.cardContainer}>
        {this.props.children}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const cardStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardContainer: {
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: "#1AAA8E",
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 5,
    shadowColor: "rgba(0,0,0, .4)",
    shadowOffset: { height: 1, width: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 1,
    elevation: 5
  }
```

And I am using the component like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.spaceAroundCenter}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>Single Select Cardlist</Text>
      <View>   <--- This View should hold the list of cards
          <Card>
            <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 30, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
              SELECTED
            </Text>
          </Card>
          <Card2>
            <Text style={{ color: "#000", fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
              NOT SELECTED
            </Text>
          </Card2>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in that case you should consider using FlatList and only pass array on that, the selected should be store in state to keep track of which one is selected.

```js
/** MAIN COMPONENT */

state = {
 selected: null,
 data: ['SELECTED','NOT SELECTED']
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.spaceAroundCenter}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>Single Select Cardlist</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={item => item}
        extraData={this.state.selected}
        renderItem={({item) => {
          return (
            <Card
              onPress={() => this.setState({ selected: item })
              selected={this.state.selected === item}
             >
              <Text style={{ color: this.state.selected === item ? "#fff" : "#000", fontSize: 30, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                {item}
              </Text>
            </Card>
          )
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

/** CARD COMPONENT */

export default class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { selected, onPress } = this.props
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[cardStyles.cardContainer, selected && { backgroundColor: '#1AAA8E'}]}>
        {this.props.children}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const cardStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardContainer: {
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 5,
    shadowColor: "rgba(0,0,0, .4)",
    shadowOffset: { height: 1, width: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 1,
    elevation: 5
  }
```